# Flutter : Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService()

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on react native but now i decided to learn flutter so first I learnt dart using [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev)

and now I was installing flutter. So I followed steps given in docs. I cloned sdk with git, added path in environment variables, installed flutter & dart extensions in vs code, ran flutter doctor. Also i created a new dart project. Till then everything was working fine but when i tried to run my app (without chaging any code) it took few minutes and throw me this error -

```
What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService().
   > Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (C:\Users\HP\.gradle\caches\6.7\fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

     Our PID: 12348
     Owner Operation: 
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: C:\Users\HP\.gradle\caches\6.7\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to run it from android studio also but got same error everytime.
Don't know why i am getting this error even my emulators are working fine

Answer (score 1):

All what you have to do is to remove the `*.lock` files by running this command:

```
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete
```

This happens usually because you installed more than one instance of Android Studio.
Ps: Take into consideration changing the `~/.gradle` if your gradle isn't located in your home